# Google Spreadsheet API - returns remote 500 error

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

Has anyone battled 500 errors with the Google spreadsheet API for google domains?

I have copied the code in this post (2-legged OAuth): http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/OAuth/Program.cs, substituted in my domain;s API id and secret and my own credentials, and it works.

So it appears my domain setup is fine (at least for the contacts/calendar apis).

However swapping the code out for a new Spreadsheet service / query instead, it reverts to type: remote server returned an internal server error (500).

```
                var ssq = new SpreadsheetQuery();
                ssq.Uri = new OAuthUri("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "me", "mydomain.com");
                ssq.OAuthRequestorId = "me@mydomain.com"; // can do this instead of using OAuthUri for queries
                var feed = ssservice.Query(ssq); //boom 500
                Console.WriteLine("ss:" + feed.Entries.Count);
```

I are befuddled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure to use the "correct" class:

not

```
//using SpreadsheetQuery = Google.GData.Spreadsheets.SpreadsheetQuery;
```

but

```
using SpreadsheetQuery = Google.GData.Documents.SpreadsheetQuery;
```

stinky-malinky

Seems you need the gdocs api to query for spreadsheets, but the spreadsheet api to query inside of a spreadsheet but nowhere on the internet until now will you find this undeniably important tit-bit. Google sucks hard on that one.